# Undefined result with a PDO query with several inner join, but correct query in SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo

I am blocked since 2 days about this problem.

I want to display an info from other table in my "info_array".

http://www.noelshack.com/2022-32-4-1660224518-type-miss.png

Td's "Type d'alarme" has the missing info, which calls another table. But i can't explain why.
All info for client call the table client, "Type d'alarme" calls type_alarme's table. There is no column connexion between them. That's why I use "inner join" in my PDO query.

I searched different method to join the result of the 2 tables but no success.

Here my HTML code for this part (it concerns "td id="alarme_type_client"></td") :

```
 <table id="info_client" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>Date de naissance</th>
        <th>Adresse</th>
        <th>Adresse mail</th>
        <th>Téléphone</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Type d'alarme</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr id=<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>>
        <td id="id"></td>
        <td id="nom"></td>
        <td id="prenom"></td>
        <td id="date" name="date"></td>
        <td id="adresse"></td>
        <td id="mail"></td>
        <td id="tph"></td>
        <td id="age"></td>
        <td id="alarme_type_client"></td>
        <td><button data-id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>" type="button" class="hide_client">Masquer client</button></td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My ajax function :

```
 $(".info").click(function () {
      var datas = {
        cmd: 'id_client',
        id_client: $(this).attr('data-id'),
      };
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "function.php",
        data: datas,
      }).done(function (sendinfo) {
          $('#alarme_type_client').html(sendinfo.nom_type_alarme),
          console.log(sendinfo.nom_type_alarme);
        
      });
    });
```

My PHP function :

```
    function read_type(){
  global $db;
  $id_client = $_GET['id_client'];
  $sql = "SELECT nom_type_alarme FROM type_alarme
  INNER JOIN alarme on type_alarme.id_type_alarme = alarme.id_type_alarme
  INNER JOIN client ON alarme.id_client=client.id_client
  WHERE id_client = :id_client";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':id_client', $id_client, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  $sendinfo = $query->fetch();
  print_r($sendinfo);
  return ($sendinfo);
}
```

http://www.noelshack.com/2022-32-4-1660225072-resultat-sql.png

In Heidi SQL (Laragon), the query works. I use the 2 inner join 'cause alarme is my principal table which union the info what I need

It displays the info client if I erase the " type_alarme.nom_type_alarme" at the beginning of query.

Any ideas ? I don't find solution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are not joining the `type_alarme` table at all. Why? Because in your SQL query you have a semicolon `;` just before you do `INNER JOIN type_alarme`. So the query is interrupted there and hence the `type_alarme.nom_type_alarme` in the `SELECT` clause doesn't know which table and column is that.

Remove the semicolon and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I removed the ";" and not success... Same after the "from client". Another idea?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, if I put "type.alarme.nom_type_alarme", nothing info can be display. In dev tools, in network, the response says "false" only...

Comment: You are making a lot of typos, It should be `type_alarme.nom_type_alarme`, underscore instead dot in type_alarme.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I don't see difference ?